# Odoo 13-14 get current popup model

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13, odoo-14

I was wondering if there is a way in Odoo 13-14 to know if currently there is a popup opened and if we can know the model of the current popup.
In the below image, I would like to know the model of the popup (i.e. res.partner).[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after much digging I found that there is a JS module called **web.view_dialogs** and inside it there is a method called **open**. Inside any function I console logged **this**, and it returned a dictionary with much information inside it, one of them is the model (res_model) and even the view type